# change rules in yii URL manager for friendly URLs

Tags: url, yii, url-rewriting, yii-url-manager

I've got a controller that requires two parameters

```
 public function actionIndex($type = 'recent-jokes',$offset = 0)
 // rest of codes
```

I want the URL to be like this so it can get the params from the URL

**something.com/items/type/offset**

right now here is my Config in my main.php

```
 'rules'=>array(
    ''=>'items/index',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
),
```

could you help me out here :)
thanks a lot for this awesome community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 'rules'=>array(
    'items/<type:\w+>/<offset:\w+>' => 'items/index',
    /* other rules */
  ),
```

There you go.

Comment: just one more tiny question, how do I get the value of offset in view?

Comment: you could pass the value to the view in the controller